# Cannot read properties of undefined in CSS Module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, css-modules

I am having a component of a form and I am adding `classNames` that have variables inside of them, the variables type is string and I am having this error in the console
`SearchInput.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Hamburger')`
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchIcon from '../../images/search.svg'
import appCSS from '../CSS/App.module.css';

export default function SearchInput({requestedBy, navStatus}) {
  

  return (
    <form className={`${appCSS.searchbarForm[requestedBy]} ${appCSS.searchbarForm[navStatus]}`}>
      <input type="text" placeholder='Search for courses or teachers'/>
      <button type='submit'>
        <img src={SearchIcon} alt="search icon" />
      </button>
    </form>
    
  )
}
```

I am running the latest version of react with "react-scripts": "5.0.1", and "css-loader": "^6.7.3"

in the CSS all classNames are checked, they are all correct

Comment: Can you add `searchBarForm` from appCSS ?

Comment: How is that? What do you mean?

Comment: I meant update your question with that information.